# What if I am not given the labels of a Karnaugh map?

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Simplify this expression represented by the map
>
> $$\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1
>  & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}$$
>
> With variables $a,b,c,d$.

Should I be concerned I am not given the labels at the sides? I mean, can I interpret the map as

$$\begin{matrix} & ab & ab' & a'b' & a'b\\ cd &  1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ cd' &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ c'd' & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ c'd & 1 & 1
 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}$$

Or

$$\begin{matrix} & ac & ac' & a'c' & a'c\\ bd &  1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ bd' &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ b'd' & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ b'd & 1 & 1
 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}$$

Or etc etc?

Comment: Yes, you should be concerned. The question as you have stated here is ambiguous. If this is on a professor's homework, I would ask him for clarification.

Comment: Maybe there was a "canonical" labeling agreed upon in previous questions or the lectures? Otherwise, you should ask him